# Is there any way in SVN so that when viewing the log, the checkins done by a particular user should not be visible

Tags: svn

Is there any way in SVN so that when viewing the log, the checkins done by a particular user should not be visible.

Here is why this is required
We are using continuous build server team city, which does some checkins into svn repository during each build, and during various other events, the net effect is that if we view the svn log we see hundreds of checkins from TeamCity, because of this it becomes difficult to view checkins done by fellow developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  But you can output the log in XML format (`svn log --xml`) and then use any available scripting language (e.g. [ruby with Nokogiri](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/nokogiri-talk/2009-June/000333.html), [Powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/03/26/use-powershell-to-parse-an-xml-file-and-sort-the-data.aspx), etc. ) to parse and filter the XML.

Comment: There exists one simpler way as well, in SVN log viewer's filter textbox type !team, it will exclude all the log entries where user name starts with "team"

Answer (score 0):

As @JacobM said you need to filter the log output in some fashion. I have precisely the same need so, if you are on Windows, you can use `Get-SvnLog`, a PowerShell cmdlet from my open-source library. Here is how I filter out check-ins from CruiseControl:

```
Get-SvnLog -ByFile | ? { $_.author -ne "cruisecontrol" } | ft -AutoSize
```

You can do a lot more with `Get-SvnLog` -- to see the API go to my [API Bookshelf](http://cleancode.sourceforge.net/wwwdoc/APIbookshelf.html) and drill down to *PowerShell*, then *SvnTools*. The documentation currently has 16 examples illustrating how to:

- show checkins for the last 24 hours;
- show files committed by particular authors;
- show number of commits per day;
- show most frequently committed files;
- and more...

You will also find there a download link for the code in the top menu bar.